# Magento2 CLI won't run locally

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade, cli

I can run php bin/magento on my remote server, but locally, when i attempt to run it, I get the following errors:

```
D:\Magento2>php bin/magento
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface in D:\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dyn
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\Magento2\bin\magento:0
PHP   2. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct() D:\Magento2\bin\magento:22
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->__construct() D:\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php:83
PHP   4. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands() D:\Magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:91
PHP   5. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands() D:\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php:112
PHP   6. Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() D:\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php:140
PHP   7. Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() D:\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php:57

Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface in D:\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\

Call Stack:
    0.0002     124312   1. {main}() D:\Magento2\bin\magento:0
    0.0320     845168   2. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct() D:\Magento2\bin\magento:22
    1.0122   12222368   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->__construct() D:\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php:83
    1.0180   12586728   4. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands() D:\Magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:91
    1.0189   12625928   5. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands() D:\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php:112
    4.1712   39443128   6. Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() D:\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php:140
    4.1712   39443384   7. Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() D:\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager
```

I'm working in developer mode, with all caches off. This started occuring after upgrading from 2.0.X to 2.1.0rc2

It seems like Symfony isn't working properly...

Comment: What version of PHP is your local server running?

Comment: LOCAL - PHP 5.6.19 (cli) (built: Mar  2 2016 20:08:25)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
SERVER- PHP 5.6.21-1~dotdeb+7.1 (cli) (built: Apr 29 2016 13:07:22)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but i've found that updating the remote server, then synchronizing the files to my local machine cleared up any issues.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer. Even if it's not the best, it worked for you and nobody provided a better one yet

Answer (score 1):

- Check if \Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface exists
  as it is called in lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Console/Cli.php:140
- Check \Magento\SampleData\Console\CommandList as it extends Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface that may not exist.
- Check app/etc/di.xml if it has correct preference for Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface.
- Clean cache.

Comment: \Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface doesn't have a constructor.  Not quite sure why magento is trying to call it.  I'm not using any sample data. I'm checking di(s) now....  lib/internal? That doesn't exist.

Comment: check app/etc/di.xml it it has correct preference for Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface

Answer (score 0):

Can happen due to permissions, try:

```
chmod 777 -R .
```

(Or more secure equivalent) in the application directory and re-run your command.